# SQL: select rows in table A where count of rows in table B equals x

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two simple tables (mySQL database) for a chat application. The first one is "Chats" where meta data like the title is stored and the second one is "Chat_Users" where the information about which user is a member of which chat is stored. This table looks like the following example:

[image: Chat_User example data]

Now I have to select the IDs of the chats where there are exactly 2 users in it. I thought this is not a big deal but unfortunately I am struggling with this task more than expected. What I already tried was to count the rows in "Chat_Users" and then only selecting those where this number equals 2:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Chats
  JOIN Chat_Users 
    on Chat_Users.ID_Chat = Chats.ID 
 WHERE Chat_Users.ID_User = 200001
 GROUP 
    BY Chat_Users.ID_Chat
     , Chat_Users.ID_User
 HAVING COUNT(Chat_Users.ID_Chat) = 2
```

In this example the query uses a request from the user with the ID 200001 and the expected result is to return everything from the rows in "Chat" with the ID 1 and 5. Chat 4 has four members so it should not be selected.

The actual result from the query above is nothing (empty response) but I don't understand why it is not working. It seems like
`COUNT(Chat_Users.ID_Chat)`
always equals 1 instead of the actual users in the specific chat.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want exactly two users, then:

```
select chat_id
from chat_users
group by chat_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

If you want one of those users to be `200001`, then use a `having` clause:

```
select chat_id
from chat_users
group by chat_id
having count(*) = 2 and
       max(user_id = 200001) > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The second approach you provided seems to work but I don't understand the max() function in it. Why is it needed?

Comment: @Flexl . . . It is essentially doing an aggregate boolean or.  If the condition ever evaluates to true, then it returns "1".

Answer (score 0):

The way you have the GROUP BY, you will only get a count of 1.

Change to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Chats
INNER JOIN Chat_Users on Chat_Users.ID_Chat = Chats.ID 
WHERE Chat_Users.ID_User = 200001
GROUP BY Chat_Users.ID_User
HAVING COUNT(Chat_Users.ID_Chat) = 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I tried this already and it didn't work because it throws a "SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column" error.

Comment: You probably need to list the fields from your Chats table in that GROUP BY

Comment: Yeah I thought the same but then you get the query posted in the question above with the empty result. But never mind, it looks like the second answer works out just fine :-)